# Влияние StatusBar`a на дизайн android-приложения

Tags: android

Добрый день. Как все знают, что в версиях >=21 API присутствует `StatusBar`. Из этого следует, что при одинаковым дизайне на устройствах `<21` и `>=21`  будут немного отличаться элементы из-за величины `StatusBar`-a. Собственно вопрос: как правильно строить дизайн приложения для разных устройств, ведь в `xml` файле не поставить условие проверки версии. Верстать программно тоже не особо хочется. Знатоки, Ваше слово! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно создать несколько xml-layouts, которые будут отображаться в зависимости от версии Android. Собственно, цитата непосредственно с сайта разработчиков:

> Если в создаваемых согласно рекомендациям Material Design макетах
>   отсутствуют новые атрибуты XML, представленные в Android 5.0 (уровень
>   API 21), такие макеты поддерживаются в предыдущих версиях ОС Android.
>   В противном случае необходимо предоставить альтернативные макеты.
>   Можно также предоставить альтернативные макеты для настройки внешнего
>   вида приложения в более ранних версиях Android.

Создайте файлы макета для Android 5.0 (уровень API 21) в `res/layout-v21/`, а также файлы альтернативного макета для более ранних версий Android (в `res/layout/`). Например, `res/layout/my_activity.xml` — это альтернативный макет для `res/layout-v21/my_activity.xml`.

Чтобы сделать код более компактным, определите стили в `res/values/`, измените стили в `res/values-v21/` для новых API, а также используйте наследование стилей, определив основные стили в `res/values/` и задав наследование из них в `res/values-v21/`.

Comment: Благодарю, почему-то пропустил этот момент...

Comment: А нужно ли как-то программно описывать создана ли директория layout-v21 или андроид сам проверит?

Comment: У вас есть какой-то фрагмент или активити. Когда, вы для них применяете ваш лейаут, то Android будет использовать оптимальный. Если API 21 версии, то он сам выберет  `res/layout-v21/`, если же версия ниже, то будет взят лейаут из `res/layout`. Перед этим вам требуется самим создать все нужные директории, и поместить туда ваши файлы.